# Shortcuts to switch to the sidebar and manipulate it

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, 20.04, focal.
I'd like to access the sidebar/dock using shortcut keys.
To be more  precise, I'd like to choose option of the menu that's regularly displayed when a sidebar icon is right-clicked, mainly "New Window", "All Windows", and "Quit". But I want to do it without using the mouse at all.
For this purpose I suppose I need a shortcut to focus on the sidebar, and then use the arrows and the enter key in order to select its options.
How may I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: you mean Ubuntu Dock? there is default shortcut Super+Number

Comment: You should try https://github.com/davatorium/rofi. It's better than dock or sidebar.